# Why does my "Text to Binary Converter" not work in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary, converters

Okay so I wanted to learn binary to write programs, so I could be able to say, "I can code in binary at 15 years old". I built this program but it prints the same incorrect values every time.

```
lowerCaseLetters = {
"a" => 01100001,
"b" => 01100010,
"c" => 01100011,
"d" => 01100100,
"e" => 01100101,
"f" => 01100110,
"g" => 01100111,
"h" => 01101000,
"i" => 01101001,
"j" => 01101010,
"k" => 01101011,
"l" => 01101100,
"m" => 01101101,
"n" => 01101110,
"o" => 01101111,
"p" => 01110000,
"q" => 01110001,
"r" => 01110010,
"s" => 01110011,
"t" => 01110100,
"u" => 01110101,
"v" => 01110110,
"w" => 01110111,
"x" => 01111000,
"y" => 01111001,
"z" => 01111010
}

puts "Type your message in English please, and \n -I the program will translate it into BINARY!!-"
userMessage = gets.chomp

puts "Your message in English says: \n >#{userMessage}"
lowerCaseLetters.each {
    |letter, number|
    print "#{number},"
}
```

So when I run this program no matter what I type, the program outputs these values. Even if I type in one value, or 6 values (thats the highest I've been up so far.... giggity)

Here are two examples from the terminal.
Example 1:

```
Type your message in English please, and 
 -I the program will translate it into BINARY!!-
j
Your message in English says: 
 >j
294913,294920,294921,294976,294977,294984,294985,295424,295425,295432,295433,295488,295489,295496,295497,299008,299009,299016,299017,299072,299073,299080,299081,299520,299521,299528,
```

Example 2:

```
Type your message in English please, and 
 -I the program will translate it into BINARY!!-
jeebs
Your message in English says: 
 >jeebs
294913,294920,294921,294976,294977,294984,294985,295424,295425,295432,295433,295488,295489,295496,295497,299008,299009,299016,299017,299072,299073,299080,299081,299520,299521,299528,
```

Where and why am I having syntax errors? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Numbers beginning with `0` are reserved for octal representation so try this as a workaround:

```
lowerCaseLetters = { "a" => '01100001', "b" => '01100010',
  "c" => '01100011', "d" => '01100100', "e" => '01100101',
  "f" => '01100110', "g" => '01100111', "h" => '01101000',
  "i" => '01101001', "j" => '01101010', "k" => '01101011',
  "l" => '01101100', "m" => '01101101', "n" => '01101110',
  "o" => '01101111', "p" => '01110000', "q" => '01110001',
  "r" => '01110010', "s" => '01110011', "t" => '01110100',
  "u" => '01110101', "v" => '01110110', "w" => '01110111',
  "x" => '01111000', "y" => '01111001', "z" => '01111010'
}

puts "Type your message in English please,"
puts "and I the program will translate it into BINARY!!-"

userMessage = gets.chomp.split('')

puts "Your message in English says: "
userMessage.each {|letter| print lowerCaseLetters[letter] + " " }
puts
```

So inputting `'ab'` returns: `01100001 01100010`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at this tutorial about converting string to binary.

http://blog.anidear.com/2011/11/convert-string-to-binary-in-ruby.html

Ruby has built in function for that. 
Bonus information with Ruby built-in Base64 encoder/decoder for your future references.

You can also, check out this online converter of string to binary to check your results.

http://binary.online-toolz.com/tools/text-binary-convertor.php

http://codebeautify.org/binary-string-converter

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Where and why am I having syntax errors?

The good news is you don't have any [syntax errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error). The bad news is you do have logical errors and they are much harder to debug.

#### How to debug Ruby

The easiest way is IRB, a tool that lets you interactively execute Ruby expressions (this is called a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)). You can launch it by typing `irb` in your terminal window:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0>
```

Enter a Ruby expression and IRB will show its result:

```
irb(main):001:0> 1 + 2
#=> 3
irb(main):002:0>
```

#### Binary numbers

Now, let's examine one of your binary numbers:

```
irb(main):002:0> 01100001
#=> 294913
```

The same weird output. What's going on?

Ruby allows you to write numbers in different [bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) by using a special prefix. The documentation for [number literals](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Numbers) gives some insight:

> You can use a special prefix to write numbers in decimal, hexadecimal, octal or binary formats. For decimal numbers use a prefix of `0d`, for hexadecimal numbers use a prefix of `0x`, for octal numbers use a prefix of `0` or `0o`, for binary numbers use a prefix of `0b`.

Your number starts with `0`, so `01100001` is interpreted as an *octal* number:

**1100001**<sub>8</sub>
=
**1** × 8<sup>6</sup> +
**1** × 8<sup>5</sup> +
**0** × 8<sup>4</sup> +
**0** × 8<sup>3</sup> +
**0** × 8<sup>2</sup> +
**0** × 8<sup>1</sup> +
**1** × 8<sup>0</sup>
=
262,144 + 32,768 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1

= 294,913

To enter a *binary* number, you have to use the `0b` prefix: (I'm assigning the number to a variable called `number` so we can refer to it later on)

```
irb(main):003:0> number = 0b01100001
#=> 97
```

**01100001**<sub>2</sub>
=
**0** × 2<sup>7</sup> +
**1** × 2<sup>6</sup> +
**1** × 2<sup>5</sup> +
**0** × 2<sup>4</sup> +
**0** × 2<sup>3</sup> +
**0** × 2<sup>2</sup> +
**0** × 2<sup>1</sup> +
**1** × 2<sup>0</sup>
=
0 + 64 + 32 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1

= 97

#### Formatting numbers

But why does Ruby output `97` instead of `01100001`? This is because when printing an object, Ruby calls the object's `to_s` method. Our number is a `Fixnum`:

```
irb(main):004:0> number.class
#=> Fixnum
```

The documentation for [`Fixnum#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) reveals that the method takes an optional argument `base` with a default value of `10`:

> **to_s(base=10)**
>
> Returns a string containing the representation of `fix` radix `base` (between 2 and 36).

Let's try `2` instead:

```
irb(main):005:0> number.to_s(2)
#=> "1100001"
```

That looks good, but the leading 0 is gone. To get it back, we can use a more powerful method called [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) which allows us to specify the format precisely:

```
irb(main):006:0> sprintf('%08b', number)
#=> "01100001"
```

`%08b` means:

- `%` starts a format sequence
- `0` pad with zeroes
- `8` width is 8 digits
- `b` binary number

#### Applied to your program

The letter hash has to be written as: (in Ruby we use snake_case for variable names)

```
lower_case_letters = {
  "a" => 0b01100001,
  "b" => 0b01100010,
  "c" => 0b01100011,
  # ...
  "z" => 0b01111010
}
```

The output can be gathered via: (just fixing the variable name)

```
user_message = gets.chomp
```

But in order to print the hash value for each character in `user_message`, you have to traverse the characters (not the hash). The corresponding method is called [`String#each_char`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-each_char):

```
user_message.each_char do |character|
  number = lower_case_letters[character]
  printf('%08b', number)
end
```

I'm using `printf` in the above code. It's equivalent to `print sprintf(...)`.

#### A little refactoring

`String` has another method [`each_byte`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-each_byte). It works like `each_char` but instead of passing each character to the block, it passes each byte:

```
user_message.each_byte { |byte| printf('%08b', byte) }
```